Usa-se o subjuntivo em algum caso em que não há expressão de dúvida?
Considere a frase

assim, não há solução inteira s tal que s divide k.

Ela satisfaz a gramática? Tenho a impressão de que talvez pudesse ser

assim, não há solução inteira s tal que s divida k.

Ouço dizer que quando uma expressão sugere dúvida, que deve se usar o subjuntivo como em

Talvez ele não faça questão de ir com a gente.

Mas na frase sobre a "solução inteira s", não há qualquer dúvida lá: o redator afirma categoricamente que s não divide k.  Como posso compreender a gramática aí de uma vez por todas?  Sinto que ainda não sei usar o subjuntivo.

talvez introduce uma dúvida, sim. Mas não no seu exemplo matemático. Quem falou que isso leva o subjuntivo?

No exemplo

assim, não há solução inteira s tal que s divide k

de fato não há dúvida expressa, mas isso não se manifesta no tempo verbal de "dividir", mas sim no de "haver": "não há" ao invés de, e.g., "não haveria".
Na verdade, eu diria que o exemplo também estaria correto com o conjuntivo, apesar de não me 'soar bem' e de não ser usual em textos matemáticos:

assim, não há solução inteira s tal que s divida k

Não é difícil achar sentenças do tipo com o conjuntivo, como:

a) Encontre o número b tal que a reta y=b divida a região delimitada pelas curvas [...]
b) Dê exemplo de uma função f que seja descontínua, mas tal que |f| seja contínua.

Contudo, o indicativo é mais comum (e me parece uma opção superior no exemplo (a) acima — note-se ser uma tradução). Suspeito que uma razão importante para o uso preferencial do indicativo é essa ser a leitura natural de expressões matemáticas, no sentido de que "a=b" lê-se quase automaticamente "a [é] igual a b", independentemente do tempo verbal que, por extenso (e talvez noutro contexto) a frase pedisse.
Além disso, pode-se considerar que há frases implícitas nessas construções, por exemplo:


assim, não há solução inteira s tal que s divide k
= assim, não há solução inteira s tal que [a condição] s divide k [é satisfeita]
encontre uma solução inteira s tal que s divida k
encontre uma solução inteira s tal que s divide k
= encontre uma solução inteira s tal que [a condição] s divide k [é/seja satisfeita]


Re: "Sinto que ainda não sei usar o subjuntivo.", penso que explicar todos os usos do subjuntivo sairia do escopo desse site de perguntas e respostas, mas, se é o "que" que te leva a pensar que a frase pediria o subjuntivo, de forma alguma esse é sempre o caso. Um bom exemplo disso, da Infopédia, é

Nas línguas que o possuem, o conjuntivo estabelece, por oposição com o indicativo, valores semânticos muito marcados, que distinguem frases como as que se seguem:
i) Procuro um livro que fale do 25 de abril. (Conjuntivo)
ii) Procuro o livro que fala do 25 de abril. (Indicativo)
Pelo contraste entre as frases i e ii, pode constatar-se que o conjuntivo cria um significado não específico e indeterminado do pronome relativo, reforçado pelo artigo indefinido, enquanto que o indicativo, pelo contrário, apresenta uma referência nominal específica e determinada, a par do uso confirmativo do artigo definido.

Note exatamente o mesmo argumento se aplica ao exemplo (b) acima ("uma função [...] que seja").
Outras fontes genéricas para o subjuntivo incluem:

https://ensina.rtp.pt/explicador/tempos-e-modos-verbais/
https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/uso-de-tempos-do-conjuntivosubjuntivo-preterito-perfeito-composto-pret-mais-que-perfeito-composto-e-/36077
https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-uso-do-conjuntivo/9690
e, claro, muitas perguntas por aqui mesmo.


Caro @stafusa, a conversa com você é realmente valiosa.  Realmente é o "que" que me leva a pensar no subjuntivo.  Agora sei do tanto que não sei.  Li suas referências e elas me deixaram claro que o assunto é muito mais complicado do que eu esperava que fosse.  Muito obrigado!
